# calenderDialog selected date splitted in textview error

Tags: android

I am using this code in order to get date in this format : `dd/mm/yyyy`.
Now I want to split the TextView displayDate so that I can get day, month and year separately to parse them in a web service .

```
    displayDate.setText("Date");
    displayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    arrivee.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );
            dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
        }
    });
```

I tried this :

```
    CharSequence StringDate =  displayDate.getText();
    StringDate  = "jj/mm/yyyy";
    String[] split =  StringDate.split("/");

    String jj = split[0];
    String mm= split[1];
    String yy= split[2];
```

And then I called them this way :

```
    //date
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("frmday", jj));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("frmmonth", mm));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("frmacty",yy ));
```

And I have got this error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder     
 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I know that day, month and year are Int but the TextView has String as default type how can I correct this error?

Thanks.

Comment: at what line of code you are getting this error?

Comment: here :    CharSequence StringDate =  displayDate.getText(); i edit it to this :  String StringDate = displayDate.getText().toString();  and then i got a Null pointer exception

Comment: Is NPE at same line?

Comment: @IlhemNemri did u solve this or you can update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

I splitted it this way

```
         @Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int yearOfYear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + yearOfYear;
    displayDate.setText(date);
    String[] split =  date.split("/");
    day = split[0];
    month = split[1];
    year = split[2];
}
```